# How to stop Flutter from generating nullable i18n string

Tags: flutter

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  i18n: any
```

It used to generates resource file like this:

```
import 'package:i18n/i18n.dart' as i18n;
String get _languageCode => 'en';
String _plural(int count, {String zero, String one, String two, String few, String many, String other}) =>
```

But now it generates like this:

```
import 'package:i18n/i18n.dart' as i18n;
String get _languageCode => 'en';
String _plural(int count, {String? zero, String? one, String? two, String?few, String? many, String? other}) =>
```

I knew the latest dart does support nullable type, but my existing apps is not. I do not have time to change all my codes to support nullable type yet.

Comment: change `i18n: any` to `i18n: 2.0.1`

Comment: Downgrade intl version . or update your code to null safety